# Connecting delegate is changing the storyboard scenes name

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, delegates, storyboard

I have some custom controls and they have their own delegates. Everything is working fine but when I am connecting the delegates from storyboard after connection all the scene name changes to delegate scene.

This is login view controller scene

[image]

Connecting the delegate
[image]

Then it is changing the view controller scene name to delegate scene
[image]

Everything else is working fine except my all the scenes name change to delegate scene.

[image]

I am not sure how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually in IB the name switches over to the connected property. So if you had a label declared as `myLabel` and connected the IB's labe to this, then it would show up as `My Label` in the IB. I guess similarly it has updated the names here as well. Why dont you try to set the name to your choice again in IB ?

Comment: If that is the case then when we set the delegate for UI element like UITextField that time it won't override the scene name. Do I need to do something extra? Reply to your suggestion, this custom control can be used in different places so I can't use the name of my choice.

Comment: Can you show how you have declared the delegates ?

Comment: Thanks @PranavKasetti

Comment: @GoodSp33d Thanks for your suggestion.